# How to divide a number by 2 as many times as possible, and then print it out in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, division, modulo

I would like to write a program that reads an integer and then divides it by 2 as many times as possible while writing the number as a product of two numbers multiplied by a number that is no longer divisible by 2.

For example:

I would like an integer: 120

120 = 2 * 2 * 2 * 15

Here is as far as I have gotten (part of it is already good in my opinion, but I got stuck here unfortunately):

```js
let num = Number(prompt('The number: '));

let i = 0;
while(!(num % 2)) { 
    num /= 2; 
    i++; 
}

let solution = Array(i).fill(2).join(' * ');

console.log(solution);
```

Comment: currently only works for numbers (in part) that are divisible by two

Comment: Well if the starting value is not divisible by 2, then there are no factors of 2 in the prime factorization, so printing zero 2's is correct.

Comment: Is it just printing out the final non-2 value that you are stuck on?

Comment: @DBS yes, the point is to leave a number (that is not divisible by two) at the end, multiplying what we have so far to get the original number

Comment: But if the *starting* number is not divisible by 2, what do you expect to happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a few steps I would take to get to your desired result:

- Keep the original value if you want to display it in the output (See the constant `initialNum` and editable `remainder`)
- If there is a remainder, push it into the array before you turn it into a string.

```js
// Keep a copy of the original
const initialNum = Number(prompt('The number: '));
let remainder = initialNum

// This is working fine and doesn't need any changes
let i = 0;
while (!(remainder % 2)) {
  remainder /= 2;
  i++;
}

// Add the required "2"s
const values = Array(i).fill(2)
// If the total isn't completely divisible by 2, add the final multiplier
if (remainder !== 1) {
  values.push(remainder)
}
// Build the output string
const solution = `${initialNum} = ${values.join(' * ')}`;

console.log(solution);
```

Comment: thanks a lot, it was a really big help!!

Answer (score 1):

You can do that

```js
let num = Number(prompt('The number: '))
let count = 0
let resp = num + ' ='

while (num > 0 && !(num & 1)) 
  {
  num >>=1
  count++
  }
resp += ' 2 *'.repeat(count)

if (count && [0,1].includes(num)) resp = resp.slice(0,-1)
else if (!count || num!==1 )      resp += ' '+ num

console.log(`count = ${count}\n${resp}`)
```

> Explanations:

It is a mathematical trick, in computer science, all numbers are represented in binary.

In binary, all even numbers end with a zero (and its divisible by 2); therefore ceut whose last digit is at 1 are not divisible by 2.
(*It's the same in base 10, all numbers multiple of 10 have a ends with a zero.*)

Dividing a binary number by 2 will always correspond to a shift to the right.
It is the same thing when we calculate in base ten, a division by 10 operate also a right shift
ex: 1230/10 = 123 ==> there is also a shift to the right.